# If Else in Java

Tags: java

I'm doing a small project for my AP CompSci class, basically, it's just take the input, determine if it's positive or not and I'm stuck with this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PositiveNumber
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
         double value = scan.nextDouble();
       
       if (value != 0)
       {
         boolean determine = value > 0;
         System.out.println("It is "+ determine + " that the number you entered is positive");
       { 
        System.out.println("Zero is a neutral number");
       }
       
       }
```

It cannot be run, "PositiveNumber.java:18: error: reached end of file while parsing"

Am I using If Else right? We haven't learned about If And Else yet, this project only require boolean but I want it to be more specific. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code has 4 `{` and only 2 `}`. The compiler expects you to finish your method and your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
    if(condition){
        //Deal with condition
    }else{
        //Deal with all other conditions
    }
```

So your if-else should look like:

```
   if (value != 0)
   {
     boolean determine = value > 0;
     System.out.println("It is "+ determine + " that the number you entered is positive");
   }else{ 
    System.out.println("Zero is a neutral number");
   }
```

Which means your code should look like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PositiveNumber
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
         double value = scan.nextDouble();
       
       if (value != 0){
         boolean determine = value > 0;
         System.out.println("It is "+ determine + " that the number you entered is positive");
       }else{
           System.out.println("Zero is a neutral number");
       } 
       
 }
      
}
```

Comment: the problem is solved, thank you so much! Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your syntax is a bit off. The compiler is being confused. Try using:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PositiveNumber
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
         double value = scan.nextDouble();
       
       if (value != 0)
       {
         boolean determine = value > 0;
         System.out.println("It is "+ determine + " that the number you entered is positive");
       } else { 
        System.out.println("Zero is a neutral number");
       }
       
   }
}
```

Here you finish off the PositiveNumber class and also add "else" to the if statement.

Comment: Thank you so much, finally got it.

Comment: No problem :) please consider accepting, or adding reputation to my answer :)